# How do i unmarshall a xml-document element into object property?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to unmarshall a element into a Class Property, which Type is Object, as to keep it generic.

I tried to build the class and marshall into xml, unmarshall it back,the result was fine.
But when i try to do this with an normal generated Xml-Document(although it has the same structure), the value of the result Class Object Property is null.

Here is my **Teststructure**:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class TestStructure {

    private Object test;

    public Object getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(Object test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

I try to marshall this, and get this **xml-document**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testStructure>
<test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">foo</test>
</testStructure>
```

However, if i try to arbitrarly build this structure Via Domsource to get the same **Xml document**:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

// root element
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("testStructure");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);
Element test = doc.createElement("test");
test.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("foo"));
test.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
test.setAttribute("xsi:type", "xs:string");
test.setAttribute("xmlns:xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
rootElement.appendChild(test);
```

and **Unmarshal** the document:

```
JAXBContext context2 = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestStructure.class);
Unmarshaller m2 = context2.createUnmarshaller();

TestStructure testobject2 =
  ( TestStructure ) m2.unmarshal(doc);

System.out.println(testobject2.getTest());
```

---

The attribute appears to be "null".

So, what went wrong?

Comment: Try using test.[setAttributeNS()](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_setattributens.asp) instead.

Answer (score 1):

woah, thanks to [W A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1989025/w-a) , i got the solution :)

You just have to modify the Element Attributes:

```
    Element test = doc.createElement("test");
test.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("foo"));
test.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi:type", "xs:string");
test.setAttribute("xmlns:xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```